# How would one turn this localstorage information a clickable link?

Tags: javascript, html

I am simply looking to make this a hyperlink. Using Local storage I grabbed The MAKE, MODEL, and YEAR from textboxes. To then insert the values into the to the link like provided below.
https://www.jdpower.com/cars/MAKE/MODEL/YEAR

tried add to add  $('result').attr('href', url); - I think I mis understood how to execute this. instead of document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = url;

.js

function generateURL(){

```
// document.getElementById('txtMake').value = localStorage.getItem('Make:');
// document.getElementById('txtModel').value = localStorage.getItem('Model:');
// document.getElementById('txtYear').value = localStorage.getItem('Year:');

var part1 = document.getElementById('txtMake').value;
var part2  = document.getElementById('txtModel').value;
var part3 =  document.getElementById('txtYear').value;
var url = "https://www.jdpower.com/cars/"+part1+"/"+part2+"/"+part3;

 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = url;
```

}

.html

```
  a tag with id="result"
```

any information given regarding my concern is appreciated.

Everything seems to work apart from the link being a hyperlink clickable.

Comment: If i am understanding the problem right, you are trying to update the HREF with a new string utilizing the base: `\`https://www.jdpower.com/cars/${part1}/${part2}/${part3}\``.... but the issue is that the HREF is not the inner HTML.  you would want to set the _href_ property

Comment: document.getElementById("result").setAttribute("href", url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct you need to set the `href` attribute. The key here is `$` calls a function accepting CSS selectors compared to `.getElementById` which just takes a name. In CSS `#` refers to an ID so you need:

`$('#result').attr('href', url);`

or without jQuery

`document.getElementById('result').setAttribute('href', url);`

Answer (score 1):

If the 'id' of your link (A element) is "result", use:

```
 $("#result").attr('href', url) ;
```

With the # prefix you are addressing a 'named' element. Without the # you are addressing a group of (or class of) elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use setAttribute method

> document.getElementById("result").setAttribute("href", url);